# Are GCM Registration Ids unique for multiple apps on the same device?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application that receives notifications using `GCM`. I register a terminal:

```
GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
```

To get Registration Id I call :

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

If I use the same SENDER_ID and API_KEY for different apps, will the **Registration ID** be different for each app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Registration Id will be different for each App.

Comment: Is the ID also different per each compilation of the same app? eg. Will different revisions of the same app record different IDs?